# cakephp add associated model on manual login

Tags: cakephp, authentication, model-associations

In cakephp I have two Models `User` and `Account`, `User belongsTo Account` model, now on logon by cakephp `UsersController->login` method the the associated table automatically added to session variable but when I manually login by `$this->Auth->login($user['User'])` only User Model data added in the Session variable, how can I achieve Account data Session on manual login?

Comment: What does your login method in the UsersController look like? Also, what version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: I am using CakePHP 2.3.0, and my login method is simple cakephp method which uses if ($this->Auth->login()) to login a user, but Account model is connected by belongsTo relation, so after login the data from Account model also added to the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually logging in using `$this->Auth->login($data);` will populate the session with `$data`, as stated in the documentation: http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-AuthComponent.html#_login

The solution is to login all the data you want. In your case:

```
$this->Auth->login($user);
```

Where `$user` contains the Account data.

Comment: I noticed there is difference on generating session between this two methods, the normal `$this->Auth->login()` method giving array in form:-`array(
 'id' => '39',
 'username' => 'doctor',
 'account_id' => '3',
 'Account' => array(
  'id' => '3',
  'Name' => 'Doctor',
  'layout' => 'doctor'
 ),);`
whereas manual login `$this->Auth->login($user);` giving array in this form:-`array(
 'User'-array('id' => '39',
 'username' => 'doctor',
 'account_id' => '3',),
 'Account' => array(
  'id' => '3',
  'Name' => 'Doctor',
  'layout' => 'doctor'
 ),);`

Comment: You may have to fiddle with the array to get the results you want, i.e., `$loginData = $user['User']; $loginData['Account'] = $user['Account']; $this->Auth->login($loginData);`

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to doing this, all I need to find user and login by method :`$this->Auth->login($user);`
, now for manual login I have to set all components so I use `$this->Session->write('Auth.User', $user);` to write all data in session Component which add Associated tables in Session.